# select single value into multi rows oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select one value and retrieve it into multi rows i tried to search about this case but i didn't find the write way to sole it and

and finaly sorry for my English

Comment: Please show some sample data and how you want the output to be displayed. Also, it would be nice to show your attempts at writing a query for this.

Answer (score 0):

try `select your_value, t.* from table t`

Comment: Actually, you don't need `t.*`, since writing `SELECT your_value from T` will be enough to show `your_value` for as many rows there are in the table.